# UIWebview in UIScrollview with images, left most goes white

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

UIScrollView with x images all with frames for next to each other and they all work fine, scrolling, etc.

There is one UIWebView in the ScrollView SubViews that is set to hidden.  When a web page is desired the WebView is set to the frame of the image (in page did load), the image is hidden and the WebView is set to not hidden.

All is working fine except when this is done for the image at the left most position in the Scroll View, the Web View seems to start to display the web page (after a page did load event) but then goes white and that is it.  The web view and the scroll view seems to be in a very bad state.  Trying to hide the Web View , etc does not work.  This only happens for the left most image, otherwise everything else seems to be working fine.  The only fix right now is to stop and start the app.  This is a scrollview that has been working fine and is defined in the UI editor.  The ImageViews and WebView are defined at run time.

Any comments on how to fix this?

If the leftmost position is ignored for the scroll view (does not make web view visible), all works fine.

SDK 4.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tip from the docs: "You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects."

Comment: Nothing like having nice graphical objects that can't be used inside each other......Why make a scroll view at all?..... Where does it say this, which doc, etc?  I guess if you can't make it work just say don't do it.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow up, yep, but have the web view aside the scroll view instead of under the scroll view (in the graphical object tree) seems to work fine.....